# Powershell - This command cannot be run

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a C++ application that launches a ps1 script using the following command
`ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "powershell.exe", -executionpolicy RemoteSigned -File script.ps1", NULL, SW_NORMAL)`

The script contains the following

```
$version = [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version.Major
if ($version -gt 9)
{
    $app = 'C:\Windows\System32\uwfmgr.exe'
    $appargs = 'servicing enable'
    Start-Process $app $appargs
    Start-Sleep -s 5
    $appargs= 'filter restart'
    Start-Process $app $appargs
}
```

The end result should be that the Windows 10 machine (protected by UWF) should request service mode on its next reboot and the computer should restart

What happens instead is that the following error is raised

```
Start-Process : This command cannot be run due to the error: The system cannot find the file specified. 
At script.ps1:6 char: 2
+ Start-Process $app $args
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo     : InvalidOperation: (:) [Start-Process], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand
```

Edit:
Added

```
$Error[0] | FL * -Force
```

and renamed $args to $appargs

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the target path in the `$Error` variable?

Comment: When I print the $error variable, it outputs the same message that I posted earlier.

Comment: Give it the full path to the file: `-File 'Path\To\script.ps1'`. C++ and PowerShell have their own 'current working folder', so PowerShell is looking in the wrong place..

Comment: `$Args` is a reserved [special variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#args). You should not use it.

Comment: `$Error[0].TargetObject` is what i was referring to:)

Comment: When checking `$Error` I usually find it useful to do `$Error[0] | FL * -Force` so that I can see everything, not just the default output text.

Comment: Without any additional info like what was asked for, it sounds like your application is not running in a context that has access to that path. Are you running it under your user context? Is it running in an elevated session?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician, question: why did you specify a `-Force` switch?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I added the following to my script but it did not generate any output. $Error[0].TargetObject

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I removed the absolute path from the ShellExecuteA code I posted. The powershell window does open and attempt to run the ps1 file but then displays the error I noted.

Comment: @BaconBits I changed the variable name. Same error but I appreciate the note.

Comment: That's just used for troubleshooting, no need to add it in the script. If you're running it through ise, just run that code in the console

Comment: This is going to sound silly, but are you sure 'C:\Windows\System32\uwfmgr.exe' exists?  I just checked my work computer and I only find it in a subfolder of 'C:\Windows\WinSxS\' and not in the System32 folder.

Comment: @Daniel you make valid point "Unified Write Filter (UWF) is an optional Windows 10 feature"  If the optional feature is not installed then the file would be missing.

Comment: Try test-path 'C:\Windows\System32\uwfmgr.exe'

Comment: @AbrahamZinala If you don't include `-Force` then it displays the error the exact same way. If you add `-Force` it actually shows you more info.

Comment: Oh nice to know!